# UDP Packet drop - INErrors Vs .RcvbufErrors

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udp, epoll

I wrote a simple UDP Server program to understand more about possible network bottlenecks.

UDP Server: Creates a UDP socket, binds it to a specified port and addr, and adds the socket file descriptor to epoll interest list. Then its epoll waits for incoming packet. On reception of incoming packet(EPOLLIN), its reads the packet and just prints the received packet length. Pretty simple, right :)

UDP Client: I used hping as shown below:

> hping3 192.168.1.2 --udp -p 9996 --flood -d 100

When I send udp packets at 100 packets per second, I dont find any UDP packet loss. But when I flood udp packets (as shown in above command), I see significant packet loss.

**Test1:**
When 26356 packets are flooded from UDP client, my sample program receives ONLY 12127 packets and the remaining 14230 packets is getting dropped by kernel as shown in /proc/net/snmp output.

> cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp: 
>   Udp: InDatagrams NoPorts **InErrors** OutDatagrams **RcvbufErrors** SndbufErrors
>   Udp: 12372 0 **14230** 218 **14230** 0

For Test1 packet loss percentage is ~53%.

I verified there is NOT much loss at hardware level using "ethtool -S ethX" command both on client side and server side, while at the appln level I see a loss of 53% as said above.

Hence to reduce packet loss I tried these: 
- Increased the priority of my sample program using [renice](/questions/tagged/renice) command. 
- Increased Receive Buffer size (both at system level and process level)

Bump up the priority to -20:

> renice -20 2022 
>   2022 (process ID) old priority 0, new priority -20

Bump up the receive buf size to 16MB:

> *At Process Level:*
>   int sockbufsize = 16777216; 
>   setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF,(char *)&sockbufsize,  (int)sizeof(sockbufsize))
>   *At Kernel Level:*
>   cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default 
>   16777216 
>   cat /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max 
>   16777216

After these changes, performed Test2.

**Test2:**
When 1985076 packets are flooded from UDP client, my sample program receives 1848791 packets and the remaining 136286 packets is getting dropped by kernel as shown in /proc/net/snmp output.

> cat /proc/net/snmp | grep Udp: 
>   Udp: InDatagrams NoPorts **InErrors** OutDatagrams **RcvbufErrors** SndbufErrors
>   Udp: 1849064 0 **136286** 236 **0** 0

For Test2 packet loss percentage is 6%.

Packet loss is reduced significantly. But I have the following questions:

1. Can the packet loss be further reduced?!? I know I am greedy here :) But I am just trying to find out if its possible to reduce packet loss further.
2. Unlike Test1, in Test2 InErrors doesnt match RcvbufErrors and RcvbufErrors is always zero. Can someone explain the reason behind it, please?!? What exactly is the difference between InErrors and RcvbufErrors. I understand RcvbufErrors but NOT InErrors.

Thanks for your help and time!!!

Comment: I know this is an ancient question, but did you find out what was at the heart of this issue?  I'm trying to reproduce the InErrors > RcvbufErrors condition.

Answer (score 11):

Tuning the Linux kernel's networking stack to reduce packet drops is a bit involved as there are a *lot* of tuning options from the driver all the way up through the networking stack.

I wrote a [long blog post](https://blog.packagecloud.io/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/) explaining all the tuning parameters from top to bottom and explaining what each of the fields in `/proc/net/snmp` mean so you can figure out why those errors are happening. Take a look, I think it should help you get your network drops down to 0.

Comment: Long blog post is a dead link.

Comment: @GroovyDotCom, updated link should be probably: https://blog.packagecloud.io/monitoring-tuning-linux-networking-stack-receiving-data/.

Comment: This is a great article

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't drops at hardware level then should be mostly a question of memory, you should be able to tweak the kernel configuration parameters to reach 0 drops (obviously you need a reasonable balanced hardware for the network traffic you're recv'ing).

I think you're missing [netdev_max_backlog](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/net.txt) which is important for incoming packets:

> Maximum number  of  packets,  queued  on  the  INPUT  side, when the interface receives packets faster than kernel can process them.

Answer (score 0):

InErrors is composed of:

- corrupted packets (incorrect headers or checksum)
- full RCV buffer size

So my guess is you have fixed the buffer overflow problem (RcvbufErrors is 0) and what is left are packets with incorrect checksums.